# Angular table, checkbox in row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, pug, html-table

I have an issue with my Angular project and don't really see how to solve it.
I have a table with checkboxes on each row (each row representing a "question" item). I want the checkbox to toggle when clicking on a row or (obviously) on the checkbox.
So I wrote this (Jade) :

```
tr(ng-click="question.selected = !question.selected")
    td
        input(type="checkbox", ng-model="question.selected")
    td {{question.title}}
    td {{question.answers}}
    td etc...
```

Problem is : when I click on the checkbox, the ng-click event on the row is triggered and then the checkbox remains unchecked.
A workaround would be to put the ng-click event on each cell except the one containing the checkbox but I think it is not really a pretty way to do it.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Why use a checkbox at all if the whole row can be selected? Maybe instead of an input you should show a checkmark there based on the value of `question.selected`.

Comment: on click toggling happens automatically..no need to do it again on `ng-click`

Comment: @MatthewGreen You're right, I think I'll do it this way

Comment: @PankajParkar It happens when clicking on the checkbox yes, but I want it to happen when clicking anywhere on the line. It's easier than needing to click precisely on the checkbox

Comment: @BenjaminBini you could to the way I suggested in my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation on click of `checkbox` to stop bubbling up the event, so that parent td wouldn't get click and the value will not get reset by adding `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` on checkbox.

**Markup**

```
tr(ng-click="question.selected = !question.selected")
    td
        input(type="checkbox", ng-model="question.selected", ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()")
    td {{question.title}}
    td {{question.answers}}
    td etc...
```

Comment: Awesome, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks ! #TIL

Comment: @BenjaminBini Glad to help you. Thanks :)